# Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: The specified module could not be found. Library path is 'caching_sha2_password.dll'

Tags: sql, xampp

Hi i am new to sql and this is my first time installing xammp. after installing xammp i wrote a code in command prompt to connect in my localhost

this is my code:
cd xammp\mysql\bin

mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1(after i enter.here whats happen )

ERROR 1045 (28000): Plugin caching_sha2_password could not be loaded: The specified module could not be found. Library path is 'caching_sha2_password.dll'

can someone solve this problem.thank you in advance.